# Two results are printed when headers are used in golang

Tags: go, http-headers

This is the code I'm working with:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", TestFunc)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func TestFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("test")

    // --------------------- headers ------------------------
    w.Header().Set("Accept-Charset", "utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

The code above works and prints two result (test test) every time.

When I remove the headers, code works fine and returns only "test".

What is the issue in this code?

Comment: What do you mean? What returns two results? None of your functions even return anything. Do you mean the body of the HTTP response is duplicated? How? Show us exactly what you mean.

Comment: Is your browser requesting `/favicon.ico`?

Comment: Sounds like you're getting two requests. How are you making the requests? Did you try logging the requests?

Comment: I use google chrome for request

Comment: @TimCooper: Fair enough; admittedly I've never used the standard router :)

Comment: Have you attempted to print `r.URL` to see what URLs are being requested?

Comment: Thanks @TimCooper. It requesting favicon.ico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser is likely requesting `/favicon.ico`. Printing out the value of `r.URL` in the request handler will confirm this.